# Clean way to catch errors from Azure Table (other than string match?)

Tags: c#, azure, try-catch, azure-table-storage

I'd like to get a list of all the Azure Table errors and figure out a clean way to handle them in a `try...catch` block.

For example, I'd like to not have to directly code and compare the InnerException message to `String.Contains("The specified entity already exists")`.  What is the right way to trap these errors?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that is provided in the [Azure Table Whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153401), but I'm not sure if this gives any value over smark's reply.

```
   /*
         From Azure table whitepaper

         When an exception occurs, you can extract the sequence number (highlighted above) of the command that caused the transaction to fail as follows:

try
{
    // ... save changes 
}
catch (InvalidOperationException e)
{
    DataServiceClientException dsce = e.InnerException as DataServiceClientException;
    int? commandIndex;
    string errorMessage;

    ParseErrorDetails(dsce, out commandIndex, out errorMessage);
}


          */
```

-

```
    void ParseErrorDetails( DataServiceClientException e, out string errorCode, out int? commandIndex, out string errorMessage)
    {

        GetErrorInformation(e.Message, out errorCode, out errorMessage);

        commandIndex = null;
        int indexOfSeparator = errorMessage.IndexOf(':');
        if (indexOfSeparator > 0)
        {
            int temp;
            if (Int32.TryParse(errorMessage.Substring(0, indexOfSeparator), out temp))
            {
                commandIndex = temp;
                errorMessage = errorMessage.Substring(indexOfSeparator + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    void GetErrorInformation(  string xmlErrorMessage,  out string errorCode, out string message)
    {
        message = null;
        errorCode = null;

        XName xnErrorCode = XName.Get("code", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
        XName xnMessage = XName.Get  ( "message",    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlErrorMessage))
        {
            XDocument xDocument = null;
            try
            {
                xDocument = XDocument.Load(reader);
            }
            catch (XmlException)
            {
                // The XML could not be parsed. This could happen either because the connection 
                // could not be made to the server, or if the response did not contain the
                // error details (for example, if the response status code was neither a failure
                // nor a success, but a 3XX code such as NotModified.
                return;
            }

            XElement errorCodeElement =   xDocument.Descendants(xnErrorCode).FirstOrDefault();

            if (errorCodeElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            errorCode = errorCodeElement.Value;

            XElement messageElement =   xDocument.Descendants(xnMessage).FirstOrDefault();

            if (messageElement != null)
            {
                message = messageElement.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try looking at the values in the Response, rather that the inner exception.  This is an example of one of my try catch blocks:

```
try {
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
catch (System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException ex)
{
    if (ex.Response.StatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
        return null;
    }
    throw;
}
```

Obviously this is just for the item doesn't exist error, but I'm sure you can expand on this concept by looking at the [list of Azure error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179382.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

To handle errors while adding objects to a table you can use the following code:

```
try {
  _context.AddObject(TableName, entityObject);
  _context.SaveCangesWithRetries(); 
}
catch(DataServiceRequestException ex) {
  ex.Response.Any(r => r.StatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict) 
  throw;
}
```

As said in other answer you can find a list of TableStorage errors at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179438.aspx

Answer (score 2):

See my code here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/testing-existence-of-a-windows-azure-blob.  The pattern is to catch a StorageClientException, and then use the .ErrorCode property to match against the constants in StorageErrorCode.

Comment: Thanks! What exceptions are commonly associated with: context.RetryPolicy? ..TimeOut? ..Expect100Continue? ..UsePostTunneling?  ...MergeOption? ...servicepoint.ConnectionLimit?  A guide would be quite helpful when creating robust applications.

Comment: Seems that Table will throw "System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException" instead of "StorageClientException" mentioned on your blog.  This will change my handler implementation... to what, I'm not sure yet.