# How do I ignore table storage resource not found exceptions without using table contexts?

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

In my C# application I am initializing a `CloudTable` instance via the following code:

```
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        client.DefaultRequestOptions.RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry();

        var table = client.GetTableReference(tableName);
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        return table;
```

When I execute an operation to retrieve a record from table storage, I usually do something like:

```
var realEntity = _table.Value.ExecuteQuery(StreamKeyConfigurationEntity.CreateQuery(calculatedPartitionKey, calculatedRowKey))
                       .SingleOrDefault();
```

After this has been in production for a while I noticed some 404 exceptions coming back from this line.  After looking around it appears that this is normal behavior when table storage does not have any matching entities, which is annoying.

The good news I came across several articles (like [this one](http://www.wadewegner.com/2012/04/return-empty-set-instead-of-resourcenotfound-from-table-storage) that claim that you can get around this by setting an `IgnoreResourceNotFoundException` property to `true`.

Perfect, except that it uses a `TableContext` not a `CloudTable`.  This is an issue becomes intellisense explicitly says to use the Table namespace instead of the context namespace, as the `GetTableServiceContext()` method is marked as obsolete.

Is there any way to blanket ignore resource not found exceptions so I don't have to wrap all queries in a try/catch using the `CloudTable` stuff?

Comment: Whats wrong with try/catch?

Comment: Having to do it everywhere add noise and boilerplate, and potentially obscures other `StorageException`s that I may need to know about.

Comment: Fair enough. Guess I never minded having try catch in my code. Also you can just check the exception message for if it is the 404 one you don't care about and if it is a different one just throw it again.

Comment: Yep understood.  I don't mind a one time try/catch, but right now there are at least 4 areas I know of that I need to add this try/catch with 404 specific code, and I'm sure that is missing one or two.

Comment: Does this help you at all?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739144/clean-way-to-catch-errors-from-azure-table-other-than-string-match

Comment: I agree with KallDrexx. Why return an HttpStatusCode in the result _and_ throw an exception? IMHO, pick on or the other at the very least. I prefer just returning a status code. Why the noise?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's generally dangerous for the library to just ignore certain exceptions that are returned as per the REST contract of the service. If you have particular requirements and want to ignore exceptions, you should use the build-in language features that enable this (namely, try-catch).

Comment: I guess that explains why it was removed, though I"m not totally sure I agree with it.  Why should I care as an end user if it's using REST under the hood or not, most of the time using a library to retrieve resources I would expect null or an empty list if no results were returned, regardless of the underlying implementation.

Comment: @KallDrexx What do you mean by end user? For table storage the person  using the APIs of table storage is the end user. Not the person of his application. When you are the API user you do care a lot about the implementation of the interfaces. Your implementation will depend on that.

Comment: I, as the developer coding against the library, am an end user.  If your usage of the library depends on the underlying implementation of the library then by definition that library is a leaky abstraction. Table storage could communicate via protocol buffers for all I care, that wouldn't change the library's API nor should it change how I use the library.  There's no reason that an underlying implementation of an API should be a huge care because the writers of the api could change implementations at any time, and if the outer layer doesn't reflect that then it will fail silently at runtime.